# why the code is not printing the value pointed by the pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

this is the source code

```
int main()
{
int s[4][2]={
            {1,2},
            {3,4},
            {5,6},
            {7,8},
          };
printf("%d\n",*(s+2);
return 0;
}
```

the above code is printing the base address of s[2] or (s+2) array i.e. address of element 5
but why it is not printing the value
     5

Comment: Because you need to dereference twice!

Comment: but *(s+2) means value at (s+2) element ie 5

Comment: The value at (s+2) is an array, not an integer.  (Remember this is an array of arrays)

Comment: so it should print the value at base address of (s+2)

Comment: what is the difference between (s+2) and *(s+2)

Comment: `s+2` is of type `int (*)[2]` while `*(s+2)` is of type `int [2]`. That's the difference.

Comment: @Shahbaz please elaborate more

Comment: There are already enough answers. Read them first.

Comment: printf("%u",(s+2));....and.....printf("%u",*(s+2)); ..both prints same result

Comment: The interaction of arrays and pointers are quite misunderstood in C. Try to read more about them, for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/232303/912144).

Comment: It's also worth reading the explanations of C arrays and pointer arithmetic in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/381549/18356) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18393343/18356) to another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`s` is a pointer to first element of the array `s` (after decay), i.e, the first row of array `s`. It is of type `int (*)[2]`, i.e, a pointer to an array of `2` elements. `s=2` is a pointer to 3rd row of array `s`.

On the other hand `*s` is of type `int [2]`, ie, an raay of `2` `int`s, this is because `*` is dereferencing the pointer expression `s` (which decays to the pointer to first row) which results in an array of `2` int's. Since `8s` is also an array, it will decays to the pointer to its first element, i.e, `s[0][0]`.

Now `*(s+2)` is dereferencing the 3rd row of the array `s`. It will also give an array of `2` `int`s. Further it will decays to the pointer to its first element, i.e, `s[0][2]`.
So , after the above discussion you can say that `s` is a pointer to pointer after all decay performed (not exactly).

Dereferencing a **pointer to pointer to `int`** (after decay) will give you a **pointer to `int`**. You need to again derefernce `*(s+2)` to get the value it points to.

```
printf("%d\n",*(*(s+2));
```

---

**NOTE:** `s`, `*s`, `&s`, `&s[0]`, `&s[0][0]` all are pointing to the same location but all of the are of **different types**.

`(s+2)` is a pointer to the 3rd row of the array `s`. It will give you the starting address of the 3rd row. `*(s+2)` is the pointer to the first element of the 3rd row, i.e, it will give you the address of the element `s[0][2]`. Although these both are giving you the same location value on printing but both are of different types.

Comment: what is the difference between (s+2) and *(s+2)

Comment: why printf("%u",(s+2)); and printf("%u",*(s+2)); both print same result

Comment: If  you will wait few minutes then I will answer all of your questions. Let me do edit. It will take few minutes.

Comment: @user3180902; Edited my answer. Read it now.

Comment: if this is the case then if I declare ....int a[]={1,2,3,4,5}
..and then printf("%u",*a);...then why it prints "1" not the address of a[0]

Comment: Because after decaying, `a` is of type `int *` and dereferencing an `int *` type would result in `int` type.

Comment: Sorry. I do not understand. Could you rephrase your words again?

Comment: like in your previous comment on 1-d array a[] .you highlighted a and int *.....I want to know how?

Comment: Do wanna high light latter in comment box like `/* Comment */` ?

Answer (score 1):

`*(s+2)` points to the "subarray" `{5,6}`, whose first element is `5`:

```
 *(s+0) ---> {1,2},
 *(s+1) ---> {3,4},
 *(s+2) ---> {5,6},
 *(s+3) ---> {7,8}
```

So, to get the **value pointed-to** from the *pointer*, you have to insert another "`*`", to *deference one more time* the pointer. This should work:

```
/* Dereference s+2 two times, to get the value 5: */
printf("%d\n",*(*(s+2)));
```

---

You can think of it in this way.

`*(s+2)` is a pointer to the subarray `{5,6}`.

Introduce a new intermediate variable `int * a`, equal to `*(s+2)`.

Now `a` is a (simple, one-level-of-indirection) pointer to the array `{5,6}`, actually to the first element of this array.

If you want the value `5`, you have to *dereference* the pointer, using `*a` (just like you do for ordinary pointers and one-dimensional arrays).

Now if you substitute `a` with `*(s+2)`, `*a` becomes `*(*(s+2))` (a double-dereference from `s`).

Comment: why to dereference twice..
what does *(s+2) means....doesn't it means ..value at base address of (s+2)

Answer (score 1):

Always remember in most cases , calling the name of the array returns the address of the first element of the array which is also referred as base address of the array, for instance

```
    int arr={0,1,2,3};
    int *p=arr
```

in this code, pointer `p` have the address of first element of `arr` which is of type int *.

Now let's go step by step what actually `*(s+2)`  returns , first calling the name of the array `s` returns the address of first element of the array , which in case is also an array of type `int [2]`,consequently address returned will be of type `int (*)[2]` , now adding 2 to this address will add up to give address of 3rd element of the array by simple pointer arithmetic , and after dereferencing the address you get `int [2] array` , you obviously cannot print an array.

And its also worth knowing that compiler access all arrays by pointer arithmatic , thus in `s[4][2]` element at `[3][0]` is accessed as `*(*(s+2)+0)` , you can use same way to access any element.
and if you want to refer to 3rd element by `(s+2)` , you can do `*((int *)s+2)` , in this you are explicitly casting address returned by `s` which is actually of type `int (*)[2]` to `int *`. Thou using cast unnecessarily is not a good idea,it can lead to unnecessary complications.

Always be careful while using pointers and always concentrate on the type of address it is referring to beforehand using it.

Answer (score 0):

Here `s` is a pointer to a pointer, so you can expect `*(s+2)` to print a pointer.

Try this to get the `5`: `*(*(s+2))`

Comment: what is the difference between (s+2) and *(s+2)

Answer (score 0):

`s` is an `int**`, a pointer to a pointer to an int.
`*(s+2)` is an `int*`, a pointer to an int.
`*(*(s+2))` or `**(s+2)` is the `int` you're looking for.
If you want to access the `6`, you'll need `*(*(s+2)+1)`.

Comment: No. `s` is an array type. Keep in mind that **arrays are not pointers!**

Comment: I am unable to get the concept
*(s+2) means value at base address of (s+2) which is 5
so it should print 5

Comment: what is the difference between (s+2) and *(s+2)

Comment: `*` is the dereference operator. It dereferences (returns the contents of) the thing it's operating on. So `*(s+2)` returns the contents at address `s+2`.